# Component Exception: Too many re-renders

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I' ve go a problem with passing data between screens.
Here is the screen where i'm taking input:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard} from 'react-native'
import Card from '../components/Card'
import colors from '../constants/colors';




type Props={

navigation:any
}

const AddingScreen = (props:Props) =>{

    let annmountAndProductToSend:any;

    const [enteredProduct, setEnteredProduct] = useState<string>('');
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState<any>('');
   
    
    function enteredProductHandler(enteredText:string):void
    {
        
        setEnteredProduct(enteredText);
    }

    function amountHandler(enteredText:any):void
    {
        let amountAndProduct;
        const amm = parseInt(enteredText);

        if(isNaN(enteredText) || enteredText > 1)
        {
            setAmount(enteredText);
            amountAndProduct = enteredText + ' ' + enteredProduct;
            annmountAndProductToSend = amountAndProduct;
        }
        else setAmount('')
        

    }

    function confirmProduct()
    {
      
        props.navigation.navigate('Main',{input:enteredProduct});
        setEnteredProduct('');
        setAmount('');
        
    }

    function returnToMainScreen()
    {
        props.navigation.navigate('Main')
    }

    return(
        
       
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress = {() => {Keyboard.dismiss();}}>
            <View style = {styles.inputContainer}>
                <Card style = {styles.screen} >
                    <TextInput blurOnSubmit autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholder="Nazwa przedmiotu" 
                    style={styles.input} 
                    onChangeText={enteredProductHandler} //1.onChangeText pobiera wpisany text i wysyła do goalInputHandler
                    value={enteredProduct}
                    />
                     <TextInput keyboardType = "number-pad" 
                    placeholder="Ilość" 
                    style={styles.input} 
                    onChangeText={amountHandler} //1.onChangeText pobiera wpisany text i wysyła do goalInputHandler
                    value={amount}
                    />
                
               <View style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
                   <View style = {styles.button}>
                <Button color = {colors.accent} title = 'Dodaj' onPress = {confirmProduct}/>
                </View>
                <View style = {styles.button}>
                <Button title = 'Wyjdź' color = {colors.accent} onPress={returnToMainScreen}/>
                </View>
                </View>
                </Card> 
                
             </View>
             </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      
        
    );
};



const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    screen:
    {
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        
    },

    inputContainer:{

        flex: 0.5, 
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
      },

      input:{
        height:30,
        borderBottomColor: 'grey',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        marginVertical: 13,
        
      },

      buttonContainer:{
          flexDirection:'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'space-between' ,
          width: '60%'
      },
      
      button:{
          width:'40%',
         
      }
  });

  export default AddingScreen;
```

The data which i'm sending is in function:

```
function confirmProduct()
   {

       props.navigation.navigate('Main',{input:enteredProduct});
       setEnteredProduct('');
       setAmount('');

   }
```

And there is second screen:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { 
  StyleSheet, 
  View, 
  Button, 
  VirtualizedList,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';




import GoalItem from'../components/Goalitem';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import colors from '../constants/colors';

type Props={
  navigation:any
}

const MainScreen = (props:Props) =>{

  
  //var inputFromAdding = JSON.stringify(props.navigation.getParam('input'));
  const [products, setProducts]  = useState<any>([]);
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState<any>([])

  
 
 
 

  function addProduct(goalTitle: any):any
  {
    //if(goalTitle.length === 0) return;
    setProducts([...products,{id: Math.random().toString(), value: goalTitle}]); 
    return products;
  };


  function removeGoalHandler(goalId:any):void
  {
    setProducts((courseGoals: any[]) => 
    {
      return courseGoals.filter((goal:any) => goal.id !== goalId);
    });
  };


  function deleteListAlert():void
  {
    if(products.length >0)
    {
      Alert.alert(
        'Lista zostanie wyczyszczona!',
        'Czy aby na pewno chcesz wyczyścić liste?',
        [{text: 'Tak', style: 'destructive', onPress: deleteList},
         {text: 'Nie', style: 'cancel'}]);
    }

    else{
      Alert.alert(
        'Lista jest pusta.',
        'W liście nie ma żadnych przedmiotów.',
        [{text: 'Powrót', style: 'cancel'}]);

    }

  }

  function deleteList()
  {
    setProducts('')
  }

  
  
  //let xx = ;
 
  

  return (

    <View style = {styles.screen}>
      <Header title="Lista zakupów"/>
      <VirtualizedList 
        keyExtractor={(item:any, index) => item.id}
        data ={addProduct(JSON.stringify(props.navigation.getParam('input')))} 
        renderItem ={itemData => (
          <GoalItem 
          id = {itemData.item.id} 
          onDelete = {removeGoalHandler} 
          title = {itemData.item.value} 

          />
        )}
      />

<View style = {styles.buttonPosition}>
      <View style = {styles.button1}>
          <Button color = {colors.accent} title = "WYCZYŚĆ" onPress={deleteListAlert}/>
        </View>
        <View style = {styles.button}>
          <Button color = {colors.accent} title="+" onPress = {() => {
            props.navigation.navigate('Adding')
          }}/>
       </View>
      </View>
      </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen:{
   flex:1,
   backgroundColor: 'white',
  },

  button:{
    width: 40,
  },

  button1:{
    width: 90,
  },

  buttonPosition:{
    padding:15,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection:'row',
    backgroundColor: colors.primary,
  },

});

export default MainScreen;
```

I'm reciving the data in:

```
data ={addProduct(JSON.stringify(props.navigation.getParam('input')))}
```

and adding it in function:

```
  function addProduct(goalTitle: any):any
  {
    //if(goalTitle.length === 0) return;
    setProducts([...products,{id: Math.random().toString(), value: goalTitle}]); 
    return products;
  };
```

than returns products, which is my array of values that i'm rendering below.

The error is: Component Excepiton: Too may re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: `addProduct` gets called in your render method. And `addProduct` calls `setProducts`. State got changed with that call and therefor the component rerenders. And everything starts again. That is the cause of the error message, because you are getting an infinite loop of rerendering

Comment: @UlrichStark so do you have any idea how to do it right? :D

Comment: You could initialize your product data in your initial useState call, or within a useEffect.

Comment: @segFault you mean, sth like that:  `const [products, setProducts]  = useState<any>(JSON.stringify(props.navigation.getParam('input')));`

Comment: yea... assuming it exists, if it may not exist you may want to go with useEffect for this initial setup after you create a products state.

Comment: @segFault I also try doing it with useEffect, like that                                                               ` useEffect(() => {
    addProduct(JSON.stringify(props.navigation.getParam('input')))
   }); `                                                                                                             but in both I've got an error ** Component Exception _this.props.getItemCount is not a functon. (In '_this.props.getItemCount(_this.props.data)', '_this.props.getItemCount' is undefined) **

Comment: Not sure where that is, but sounds like a separate issue. If you aren't using class components, you can try removing the `_this` from those lines of code. If you are using class components, change `_this` to `this` without the underline.

Comment: @segFault this error was caused by counter in VirtualizedList, but anyway it's still not working, while using useEffect, nothing happens in my app

Comment: @segFault I mean buttons doesn't work, maybe you have any other ideas how to set "products" state with that input value, cos i literally tried evrything and nothing worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Porblem with passing data between screen (Too many re-renders)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66001842/porblem-with-passing-data-between-screen-too-many-re-renders)