# Porblem with passing data between screen (Too many re-renders)

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation, use-state

I've got a problem with passing data between screens. Here is the screen where I'm taking input:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {View, TextInput, Button, StyleSheet, TouchableWithoutFeedback, Keyboard} from 'react-native'
import { useGlobal } from 'reactn';
import Card from '../components/Card'
import colors from '../constants/colors';




type Props={

navigation:any
}

const AddingScreen = (props:Props) =>{
    
    let annmountAndProductToSend:any;
    
    const [enteredProduct, setEnteredProduct] = useState<string>('');
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState<any>('');
   
    
    function enteredProductHandler(enteredText:string):void
    {
        
        setEnteredProduct(enteredText);
    }

    function amountHandler(enteredText:any):void
    {
        let amountAndProduct;
        const amm = parseInt(enteredText);

        if(isNaN(enteredText) || enteredText > 1)
        {
            setAmount(enteredText);
            amountAndProduct = enteredText + ' ' + enteredProduct;
            annmountAndProductToSend = amountAndProduct;
        }
        else setAmount('')
        

    }

    function confirmProduct()
    {
      
        props.navigation.navigate('Main',{input:enteredProduct});
        setEnteredProduct('');
        setAmount('');
        
    }

    function returnToMainScreen()
    {
        props.navigation.navigate('Main')
    }

    return(
        
       
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress = {() => {Keyboard.dismiss();}}>
            <View style = {styles.inputContainer}>
                <Card style = {styles.screen} >
                    <TextInput blurOnSubmit autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholder="Nazwa przedmiotu" 
                    style={styles.input} 
                    onChangeText={enteredProductHandler} //1.onChangeText pobiera wpisany text i wysyła do goalInputHandler
                    value={enteredProduct}
                    />
                     <TextInput keyboardType = "number-pad" 
                    placeholder="Ilość" 
                    style={styles.input} 
                    onChangeText={amountHandler} //1.onChangeText pobiera wpisany text i wysyła do goalInputHandler
                    value={amount}
                    />
                
               <View style = {styles.buttonContainer}>
                   <View style = {styles.button}>
                <Button color = {colors.accent} title = 'Dodaj' onPress = {confirmProduct}/>
                </View>
                <View style = {styles.button}>
                <Button title = 'Wyjdź' color = {colors.accent} onPress={returnToMainScreen}/>
                </View>
                </View>
                </Card> 
                
             </View>
             </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      
        
    );
};



const styles = StyleSheet.create({

    screen:
    {
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center',
        
    },

    inputContainer:{

        flex: 0.5, 
        justifyContent:'center',
        alignItems:'center'
      },

      input:{
        height:30,
        borderBottomColor: 'grey',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        marginVertical: 13,
        
      },

      buttonContainer:{
          flexDirection:'row',
          alignItems: 'center',
          justifyContent: 'space-between' ,
          width: '60%'
      },
      
      button:{
          width:'40%',
         
      }
  });

  export default AddingScreen;
```

And here is the screen, where i'm passing this data (input) to add it to VirtualizedList:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
import { 
  StyleSheet, 
  View, 
  Button, 
  VirtualizedList,
  Alert,
} from 'react-native';



import GoalItem from'../components/Goalitem';
import Header from '../components/Header';
import colors from '../constants/colors';



type Props={
  navigation:any
}

//setProducts([...products,{id: Math.random().toString(), value: props.navigation.getParam('input')}]); 

const MainScreen = (props:Props) =>{

 
  const [products, setProducts]  = useState<any>([]);
  const [didAddInput, setDidAddInput] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [amont, setAmount] = useState<any>([]);

 

  function addProduct(input:string,oneadd:boolean){

   setDidAddInput(oneadd);

  if(didAddInput === true)
  {
    setProducts([...products,{id: Math.random().toString(), value: input}]); 
    return products;
  }
  setDidAddInput(false)

  };
  
  


  function removeGoalHandler(goalId:any):void
  {
    setProducts((courseGoals: any[]) => 
    {
      return courseGoals.filter((goal:any) => goal.id !== goalId);
    });
  };


  function deleteListAlert():void
  {
    if(products.length >0)
    {
      Alert.alert(
        'Lista zostanie wyczyszczona!',
        'Czy aby na pewno chcesz wyczyścić liste?',
        [{text: 'Tak', style: 'destructive', onPress: deleteList},
         {text: 'Nie', style: 'cancel'}]);
    }

    else{
      Alert.alert(
        'Lista jest pusta.',
        'W liście nie ma żadnych przedmiotów.',
        [{text: 'Powrót', style: 'cancel'}]);

    }

  }

  function deleteList()
  {
    setProducts('')
  }

  function count():number
  {
    return 50;
  }



  return (
    
    <View style = {styles.screen}>
      <Header title="Lista zakupów"/>
      <VirtualizedList 
        keyExtractor={(item:any, index) => item.id}
        //data ={addProduct(value)} 
        getItem = {addProduct(JSON.stringify(props.navigation.getParam('input')),true)}
        getItemCount = {count}
        renderItem ={itemData => (
          <GoalItem 
          id = {itemData.item.id} 
          onDelete = {removeGoalHandler} 
          title = {itemData.item.value} 

          />
        )}
      />

<View style = {styles.buttonPosition}>
      <View style = {styles.button1}>
          <Button color = {colors.accent} title = "WYCZYŚĆ" onPress={deleteListAlert}/>
        </View>
        <View style = {styles.button}>
          <Button color = {colors.accent} title="+" onPress = {() => {
            props.navigation.navigate('Adding')
          }}/>
       </View>
      </View>
      </View>
      
  );

 
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen:{
   flex:1,
   backgroundColor: 'white',
  },

  button:{
    width: 40,
  },

  button1:{
    width: 90,
  },

  buttonPosition:{
    padding:15,
    alignItems: 'stretch',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection:'row',
    backgroundColor: colors.primary,
  },

});

export default MainScreen;
```

So my data is here:

```
getItem = {addProduct(JSON.stringify(props.navigation.getParam('input')),true)}
```

I put it in console.log and it's sent right, but i've got a problem with adding it to

```
const [products, setProducts]  = useState<any>([]);
```

(products is my array of values)

I try to put a second useState to avoid multiple adding by changing state to false after adding but it changes nothing, i've got an error "Component Exception: Too many re-renders", also try to use globalState but it doesn't work. Maybe there is another and better way to change the state with input data, thanks for help :)

Comment: You are calling `addProduct` with `oneadd = true` so you are setting it to `true` every time and therefore still adding it every time.

Comment: @LindaPaiste so how can I change this state only once? I tried do it in useEffect but then after adding product list is empty and nothing happens

Comment: I'm writing an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Boolean Flag

When you call `addProduct(JSON.stringify(props.navigation.getParam('input')),true)` you are setting the second argument `oneadd` to `true`.  In the `addProduct` function, you call `setDidAddInput(oneadd);` before checking `if(didAddInput === true)`, so it will always be `true` and still execute infinite times.

Our goal is to execute once per `input`.

With a `boolean` flag, here's what you would do.  The initial value is `false`.  We only add if it is still `false` and has not been changed.  Then after adding, we set it to `true` so that it will not be run again.

You cannot `return products` before you `setDidAddInput` because nothing after the `return` will run.

```
function addProduct(input:string) {
   // only add if not already added
  if( didAddInput === false ) {
    setProducts([...products,{id: Math.random().toString(), value: input}]);
    // prevent adding again 
    setDidAddInput(false);
  }
  // always return products
  return products;
};
```

### useEffect

There is a lot that's not ideal about the above solution.  The adding of a product and the accessing of all products are handled in the same function, so we are calling the function way more times than is necessary ( even though we are only adding once ).

A `useEffect` hook is better.  We need to make sure that we set the correct dependencies so that the effect is run at the right times.  We want to run it every time that `input` changes.  (You could also include `setProducts` in your dependencies, but it won't make any difference because it never changes).

Let's define the `input` `string` that we want as a variable outside of the `useEffect`.

The addProduct functionality will exist inside of the `useEffect` callback.  We don't return anything.

```
const input: string = JSON.stringify(props.navigation.getParam('input'));

useEffect( () => {

  setProducts([...products,{id: Math.random().toString(), value: input}]);

}, [input]);
```

The effect runs automatically so `products` should get updated with the latest data.  Your `VirtualizedList` can access `products` directly.

Comment: Ok then something is wrong with the list.  You don't need `VirtualizedList` here.  Switch back to `FlatList`.  There might be other props of the list that are wrong, but that's a start.

Comment: thank you very much for help, now everything works fine :)

Comment: in `renderItem` the prop `onDelete` needs to be an arrow function in order to get the right id. `onDelete={() => removeGoalHandler(itemData.item.id)}`

Comment: i've got one more question, after opening app, there is rendered an empty component on the list (which holds input, but before typing any input so it's empty) do you have any ideas how to avoid this?

Comment: I've tried to put useEffect in condition if(input !== '') but it doesn't work

Comment: You want the condition inside the `useEffect` callback.    Does this work?  `useEffect( () => { if (input !== '') { setProducts([...products,{id: Math.random().toString(), value: input}]); } }, [input]);`

Comment: If not, log the value and see if it is actually an empty string and not something else.

Comment: if(input !== ' ') doesn't work. When I put input in console log, before typing anything it is undefined, so i change to if(input !== undefined) and now it works :) thanks for all your help!!

Comment: Great!  You can also use `if (input)` and that will filter out both `""` and `undefined`.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy